# why is my method operator returning none

Tags: python

I'm writing a polynomial class and having trouble with my getitem operator 
Here is my code for my getitem:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
        for i in range(len(self.coeffs)):
            if self.coeffs[i][1] == idx:
                return (self.coeffs[i][0])
                break
```

and here is my test code:

```
 for i in range(P1.degree() + 1):
            if P1[i] != 0:
                print(P1[i], end = " ")
```

The polynomial is 6x^14+9x^11-12x^3+42 and it returns all the nonzero coefficients however i get the output like this

```
42 None None -12 None None None None None None None 9 None None 6
```

so my question is how can i only display the coeffients and also why is none showing up anyways?

Comment: If your `if` statement never matches, `None` will be returned when the function falls off the end.

Comment: 1) All python functions implicitly returns `None` when end of function is reached. 2) You _ask your code_ to print **all** values, unconditionally. Why shouldn't it print `None` if that that's a value of `P1[i]`?

Comment: `break` after [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) is unnecessary, since `return` already leaves the current function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting
 return 0 
at the end of the function **getitem** to prevent it from returning None and instead return value 0.

This will make the check "if P1[i] != 0:" in test code to evaluate to false for values where None is coming now and then 'None' values will not get printed.